# Error message in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

[image]

Can you please help with this error. It started suddenly. I didn't do anything at my .bib file My bib file code is

```
@book{Hutton,
    author    = "Hutton, David V",
    title     = "Fundamentals of Finite Element Analysis",
    publisher = "McGraw-Hill",
    %volume   = "",
    %number   = "",
    %series   = "",
    %address  = "",
    %edition  = "",
    year      = "2003",
    %month    = "",
    %note     = "",
}
@book{Shamsher,
    author    = "Prakash, Shamsher and Sharma, Hari D",
    title     = "Pile foundation in engineering practice",
    publisher = "John Wiley and Sons Inc.",
    %volume   = "",
    %number   = "",
    %series   = "",
    %address  = "",
    %edition  = "",
    year      = "1990",
    %month    = "",
    %note     = "",
}
@book{Rao,
    author    = "Rao, Singiresu S",
    title     = "Mechanical Vibrations",
    publisher = "Peritence Hall",
    %volume   = "",
    %number   = "",
    %series   = "",
    %address  = "",
    %edition  = "",
    year      = "2011",
    %month    = "",
    %note     = "",
}
@book{Impe,
    author    = "Reese, Lymon C and Impe, William Van",
    title     = "Single piles and pile groups under lateral loading",
    publisher = "CRC Press",
    %volume   = "",
    %number   = "",
    %series   = "",
    %address  = "",
    %edition  = "",
    year      = "2011",
    %month    = "",
    %note     = "",
}
@article{Hutchinson,
    author    = "Hutchinson,J.R",
    title     = "Shear Coefficients for
Timoshenko Beam Theory",
    journal   = "Journal of Applied Mechanics",
    volume   = "68",
    %number   = "",
    pages    = "89-91",
    year      = "2001",
    %month    = "",
    %note     = "",
}
@manual{Ansys,
    title       = "Theory reference for the mechanical APDL and Mechanical Applications",
    %author     = "",
    organization    = "ANSYS",
    %address    = "",
    %edition    = "",
    year        = "2009",
    %month      = "",
    %note       = "",
}
@misc{Duke,
    author    = "Gavin, H.P",
    title     = "Structural element stiffness, mass and damping matrices",
    %howpublished = "",
    year     = "2014",
    %month    = "",
    %note     = "",
}
@book{Mutlu,
    author    = "Somer, B Mutlu and Fredsoe, Jorgen",
    title     = "Hydrodynamics around cylindrical structures",
    publisher = "World Scientific",
    %volume   = "",
    %number   = "",
    %series   = "",
    %address  = "",
    %edition  = "",
    year      = "2006",
    %month    = "",
    %note     = "",
}

@book{Journee,
    author    = "Journee, J MJ and Massie, W W",
    title     = "Offshore Hydromechanics",
    publisher = "TU Delft",
    %volume   = "",
    %number   = "",
    %series   = "",
    %address  = "",
    %edition  = "",
    year      = "2001",
    %month    = "",
    %note     = "",
}
@book{Baltrop,
    author    = "Barltrop, N DP and Adams, A J",
    title     = "Dynamics of fixed offshore structures",
    publisher = "Butterworth Heinemann",
    %volume   = "",
    %number   = "",
    %series   = "",
    %address  = "",
    %edition  = "",
    year      = "1991",
    %month    = "",
    %note     = "",
}
@book{Wilson,
    author    = "Wilson, James F",
    title     = "Dynamics of offshore structures",
    publisher = "John Wiley & Sons, Inc.",
    %volume   = "",
    %number   = "",
    %series   = "",
    %address  = "",
    %edition  = "",
    year      = "2003",
    %month    = "",
    %note     = "",
}
@book{Kattan,
    author    = "Kattan, Peter",
    title     = "Matlab guide to finite element methods",
    publisher = "Springer",
    %volume   = "",
    %number   = "",
    %series   = "",
    %address  = "",
    %edition  = "",
    year      = "2006",
    %month    = "",
    %note     = "",
}
@book{Chakraborti,
    author    = "Chakrabarti, Subrata K",
    title     = "HANDBOOK OF OFFSHORE ENGINEERING",
    publisher = "Elsevier",
    %volume   = "",
    %number   = "",
    %series   = "",
    %address  = "",
    %edition  = "",
    year      = "2005",
    %month    = "",
    %note     = "",
}
@book{Faltinsen,
    author    = "Faltinsen, O M",
    title     = "Sea loads on ships and offshore structures",
    publisher = "Cambridge University Press",
    %volume   = "",
    %number   = "",
    %series   = "",
    %address  = "",
    %edition  = "",
    year      = "1990",
    %month    = "",
    %note     = "",
}
@techreport{Upwind,
    author    = "Vries, Wybren de and Vermula and Kumar, Naveen and Patrik.Passon, (Rambøll) and Fischer, Tim and Kaufer, Daniel and Matha, Denis and Schmidt, Björn and Vorpahl, Fabian",
    title     = "UpWind – Integrated Wind Turbine Design Project No. 019945 (SES6).",
    institution = "TU Delft",
    %type     = "", 
    %number   = "",
    %address  = "",
    year      = "2011",
    %month    = "",
    %note     = "",
}

@misc{Miguel,
    author    = "Miguel, Pango A",
    title     = "Analyses of Lateral Loaded Piles with P-Y Curves - Observations on the Effect of Pile Flexural Stiffness and Cyclic Loading",
    %howpublished = "",
    year     = "2013",
    %month    = "",
    %note     = "",
}
@mastersthesis{Huang,
    author    = "Huang, J.W.",
    title     = "Development of modified p-y curves for Winkler Analysis to characterize the lateral load behavior of a single pile embedded in improved soft clay",
    school    = "IOWA State University",
    %type     = "diploma thesis",
    %address  = "",
    year      = "2011",
    %month    = "",
    %note     = "",
}
@book{Einar,
    author    = " Strømmen,Einar N. ",
    title     = "Theory of Bridge Aerodynamics",
    publisher = "Springer",
    %volume   = "",
    %number   = "",
    %series   = "",
    %address  = "",
    %edition  = "",
    year      = "2006",
    %month    = "",
    %note     = "",
}
@book{wind_explained,
    author    = "Manwell,J.F. and McGowan,J.G. and Rogers,A.L.",
    title     = "Wind Energy Explained Theory, Design and Application",
    publisher = "JOHN WILEY and SONS, LTD",
    %volume   = "",
    %number   = "",
    %series   = "",
    %address  = "",
    %edition  = "",
    year      = "2002",
    %month    = "",
    %note     = "",
}
@book{wind_handbook,
    author    = "Burton,Tony and Sharpe,David and Jenkins, Nick and Bossanyi,Ervin",
    title     = "WIND ENERGY HANDBOOK",
    publisher = "JOHN WILEY and SONS, LTD",
    %volume   = "",
    %number   = "",
    %series   = "",
    %address  = "",
    %edition  = "",
    year      = "2001",
    %month    = "",
    %note     = "",
}
@techreport{DNV_wind,
    author    = "DNV",
    title     = "Design of Offshore Wind Turbine Structures",
    institution = "DNV",
    %type     = "", 
    %number   = "",
    %address  = "",
    year      = "2014",
    %month    = "",
    %note     = "",
}
@techreport{IEC,
    author    = "IEC",
    title     = "International standards for wind turbines",
    institution = "International Electrotechnical Commission",
    %type     = "", 
    %number   = "",
    %address  = "",
    year      = "2005-08",
    %month    = "",
    %note     = "",
}
@phdthesis{Tempel,
    author      = "TEMPEL,Jan VAN DER ",
    title       = "Design of Support Structures for Offshore Wind Turbines ",
    school      = "TU Delft",
    %address    = "",
    year        = "2006",
    %month      = "",
    %keywords   = "",
    %note       = "",
}
@article{francesco,
    author    = "Petrini, Francesco and Li, Hui and Bontempi, Franco",
    title     = "Basis of design and numerical modeling of offshore wind turbines",
    journal   = "Structural Engineering and Mechanics",
    %volume   = "",
    %number   = "",
    %pages    = "",
    year      = "2010",
    %month    = "",
    %note     = "",
}
```

Comment: Welcome, remove all lines beginning with a `%`. [Quote](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Standard_templates): *Be careful if you copy the following templates, the % sign is not valid to comment out lines in bibtex files. If you want to comment out a line, you have to put it outside the entry.*

Comment: Thank you  very much .Now the errors are gone but I still get an error that says ''{'' immediately follows a field name :@ techreport::{Upwind,

Comment: The bib you have posted runs fine except for `"John Wiley & Sons, Inc."`, which should be `"John Wiley \& Sons, Inc."` (not the extra backslash).

Comment: I'd be curious about an answer as to why the syntax of bib*tex doesn't allow TeX comments. It appears to be a strange design choice in a file format that interacts with TeX and has a similar-looking syntax…